# Minimum distance question

Tags: distance-metrics, coding

I´m reading a paper on Miller codes and I´m having trouble calculating the minimum distance out of a state diagram.
The [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8240732) states in Fig. 3. that "it is easy to verify that dmin for these seven diagrams is 2,1,1,1,1,1, and 2, respectively."

[image]

The output bits each state produce are 00 for S1, 01 for S2, 10 for S3 and 11 for S4.
It also shows a Trellis diagram of the last code (g) in Fig. 3:

[image]

I know the Hamming distance of two output signals is the number of bits in wich they differ, and the distance of a code is the minimum distance between any two output symbols. Is it not 2 for all of them here?
What is the logic to calculate the above mention distances? Especially of the state diagram (g).
Thank you